# Python regex to find all between two patterns

Tags: python, regex

in my test log file, i want to find all the line between these two it can occur more than once also i did not want to exclude these two match from output

--- /b/act-builder/sandboxes/ACT-SB-RELEASE_174_THROTTLE-28378/src/junos/usr.sbin/rpd/lib/policy/atf-tests.host,linux ---

*** [atf-run.log] Error code

where the first line pattern will always start like "--- /b/act-builder/sandboxes/"

and end like "Linux ---"

and the second patern will be "Error code"

My Solution Which is not working:-

```
  file = open('atf_log_28378.txt', "r")
    for result in re.findall('^--- /b/act-builder/(.*?)Error code', file.read(), re.S):
        print 'Failed test cases:' + result + '\n'


Expected Output will be the one or more combination of these:-
--- /b/act-builder/sandboxes/ACT-SB-RELEASE_174_THROTTLE-28378/src/junos/usr.sbin/rpd/lib/policy/atf-tests.host,linux ---
    test1: [0.040247s] Failed: Test program received signal 6
    test2: [0.039347s] Failed: Test program received signal 6
[0.079804s]
scu_dcu_test (12/12): 1 test cases
    test1: [0.039158s] Failed: Test program received signal 6
[0.039262s]
Failed test cases:
    aspath_test:test1, aspath_test:test2, aspath_test:test3, aspath_test:test4, cbf_test:test1, com_test:test1, com_test:test2, cmgr_test:test1, cmgr_test:test2, lsp_regex_test:test1, match_cache_test:test1, match_cache_test:test2, match_cache_test:test3, match_cache_test:test4, match_cache_test:test5, mt_test:test1, path_attr_err_test:test1, path_attr_err_test:test2, plist_test:test1, policy_namelist_test:test1, policy_te_test:test1, policy_te_test:test2, scu_dcu_test:test1
Summary for 12 test programs:
    0 passed test cases.
    23 failed test cases.
    0 expected failed test cases.
    0 skipped test cases.
*** [atf-run.log] Error code 1 (ignored)
```

Comment: If there are more than 1 matches expected, add `re.M` flag to force `^` to match a line start position.

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: i did try that but still not working and yes there are more than one matches expected

Comment: Could you make your example a bit clearer, perhaps add code formatting to it?

Comment: So, did you try changing `re.S` to `re.M|re.S`?

Comment: yes its not working

Comment: @MartinEvans Sorry for the formatting I am using stackoverflow for first time

Comment: Your regex works [like this](https://ideone.com/8555rZ). What are the expected matches? See also [this regex fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/EMaG1q/1).

Comment: expected output is added in post

Comment: Still, that is a bit unclear: you want the part before `.*?` to be included? Then try https://ideone.com/cTsVAB

Comment: i have added the test string here https://regex101.com/r/EMaG1q/2

Comment: Is the aim to capture `Error code` entries with all lines back to the previous `--- xxxxxxx ---` line?

Comment: yes from Error Code to --- /b/act-builder/sandboxes/ACT-SB-RELEASE_174_THROTTLE-28378/src/junos/usr.sbin/rpd/lib/policy/atf-tests.host,linux ---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture all the previous lines from a line containing `Error code` back to the previous line containing `--- xxx xxxx  xxxx ---`, a non regular expression solution could be done as follows:

```
previous = []

with open('atf_log_28378.txt') as f_input:    
    for line in f_input:
        if line.startswith('--- '):
            previous = [line]
        elif 'Error code' in line:
            print ''.join(previous) + line
            previous = []
        elif previous:
            previous.append(line)
```

This would display entries such as:

```
--- /b/act-builder/sandboxes/ACT-SB-RELEASE_174_THROTTLE-28378/src/ui/lib/libjunos-dynamic-render/tests.host,linux ---
Nothing interesting in stderr hello
Failed:../../../../../../src/ui/lib/libjunos-dynamic-render/tests/drt_main.cpp:95: dri_get_dto_count() == 0

****
Failed: 1 errors
Thread test done
*** [all] Error code 255 (ignored)

--- /b/act-builder/sandboxes/ACT-SB-RELEASE_174_THROTTLE-28378/src/junos/usr.sbin/rpd/lib/trace/tests.host,linux ---
    test1: [0.039987s] Failed: Test program received signal 6
    test2: [0.039151s] Failed: Test program received signal 6
[0.079371s]

Failed test cases:
    tmtest:test1, tmtest:test2

Summary for 1 test programs:
    0 passed test cases.
    2 failed test cases.
    0 expected failed test cases.
    0 skipped test cases.
*** [atf-run.log] Error code 1 (ignored)
```

Comment: Thanks,  above code is working just fine. but still i am interested if this can be done by regx.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down buttons to select an answer as the accepted solution when you're finished.